# How do I replace last part of string using string.replace() Javascript / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in JS attempting to make a web proxy in Node.js.
I have figured out how to replace keywords in the proxy.
What I am trying to do is put a querystring containing the URL right after the content inside an attribute such as "src" for example.

Before: `"src="assets/content"`
After: `"src="assets/content?_get=https://example.org`

But its coming out like this

```
?_get=https://example.org/assets/content
```

Idk how to do this so may someone please help me out?

```
 replace(/href="/gi, 'href="' + '?_get=' + queryURL)
```

Edit: queryURL is the querystring contents

Comment: Your "before" and "after" examples are invalid because you have 3 double quotes in each. I'm assuming that the very first one (before `src`) in each shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `replace` for this, just simple string concatenation:

```js
let img = document.querySelector("img")
img.src = img.src + "?_get=https://example.org";

console.log(img.outerHTML);
```

```html
<img src="http://example.com/assets/content">
```

Answer (score 0):

If for example, you have these variables:

```js
let oldStr = "assets/content"
let extStr = "?_get=https://example.org"
```

There are two methods to add the **extStr** to **oldStr**

#### Method 1

```js
let newStr = oldStr+extStr;
// output will be "assets/content?_get=https://example.or"
```

#### Method 2 (using Regular Expression)

```js
let newStr = oldStr.replace(/$/, extStr);
// output will be "assets/content?_get=https://example.or"
```

You can read more about **$** quantifier from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_ndollar.asp)